# Sign In With Google (GIS) on Vue.js Application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-signin

Apparently google is discontinuing service for `gapi.oauth2`. I'm trying to use their new Sign in With Google tools but they are very confusing.

**Project Structure**
I have a Vue frontend where I need to allow users to sign in with google. I then need to use the OIDC server flow to authenticate them on my backend.

My file structure is the default structure that the Vue CLI gives you.

I followed these [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#gis-redirect-ux) but they don't explain how to actually give the user the opportunity to sign in. Like how do we initiate the whole flow? I thought maybe the flow was initiated by the new [Sign in With Google Button](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button) but I can not figure out how to get this button to work.

Here is how I'm trying things now:

In `App.vue` I have the following

```
created() {
    loadGSIClient().then((this.GSILoaded = true));
}
```

`googleAuth.js`

```
export function loadGSIClient() {
  console.log("loading GSI");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client";
    script.onload = () => {
      var client = window.google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
        client_id: process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID,
        scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
        ux_mode: "redirect",
        redirect_uri:
          "http://localhost:5001/sig-wig/us-central1/handleRedirect",
      });
      resolve(client);
    };
    script.onerror = (message, url, line, column, error) => {
      reject({ message, url, line, column, error });
    };
  });
}
```

Then, in my sign in file `AccessRequest` I have

```
  created() {
    var google = window.google;
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID,
      callback: () => {
        "I'm a callback";
      },
    });
    google.accounts.id.renderButton(
      document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
      { theme: "outline", size: "large" } // customization attributes
    );
  },
```

However that setup always throws the error `Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'accounts')"`

So it seems like `window.google` exists when I'm in `App.vue` but not in `AccessRequest.vue`. Is there some big misunderstanding I'm having about how all of this is supposed to work?

Is this "Sign in With Google Button" meant to work with an OIDC Server flow?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out ? If So could you post your results here for me and others that are coming across this thread looking for answers ?

Answer (score 12):

Here is My Code
First, You have to put this code index.html in public folder

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

```
<template>
 <div ref="googleLoginBtn" />
</template>
<script>
  export default(){
    mounted() {
      const gClientId = [Your Client Id]
      window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: gClientId,
        callback: this.handleCredentialResponse,
        auto_select: true
      })
      window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(
        this.$refs.googleLoginBtn, {
          text: 'signin_with', // or 'signup_with' | 'continue_with' | 'signin'
          size: 'large', // or 'small' | 'medium'
          width: '366', // max width 400
          theme: 'outline', // or 'filled_black' |  'filled_blue'
          logo_alignment: 'left' // or 'center'
        }
      )
    },
    methods: {
      async handleCredentialResponse(response) {
         console.log(response.credential)
         // Put your backend code in here
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This code example is working well for me, too. The text parameter is passing an invalid value, though. You don't get to determine your own text. There are a number of string value options to choose from. The GIS JS documentation can be found here: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference.

Comment: This is working well for me too. I have edited the code to fix a couple of things and add some common options in comments.

Answer (score -1):

To follow good practices, I would offload the logics outside the `index.html`. Here is my working implementation:

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>
<script type="module">
  import { GOOGLE_USER_ID, handleCredentialResponse } from './src/utils/oauth_google.js';
  document.getElementById("g_id_onload").setAttribute("data-client_id", GOOGLE_USER_ID);
</script>
<div id="g_id_onload"
    data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"
    data-auto_prompt="false"
    >
</div>
```

**oauth_google.js**

```
export const GOOGLE_USER_ID = import.meta.env.VITE_GOOGLE_USER_ID;


export function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
  const data = { token: response.credential };
  // Do what you need
}

window.handleCredentialResponse = handleCredentialResponse;
```

**.env**

```
VITE_GOOGLE_USER_ID=YOUR_CREDENTIAL
```

Comment: Could you explain why is this voted down?